# Assign input field value from previous page to a session and access with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

**My Question**

I have a contact form and it has a input field called

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Car">
```

and the second form with a input field called

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Home">
```

When someone clicks submit, the user is directed to a generic thank you page with a div in it as follows

```
<div class="lead_form_thankyou">Thank you message</div>
```

What I am trying to do is, assign the input field value to a session and access it while on the thank you page to display a customised Thank you message.

**My Code**

I have this code now

```
$subjectForThankYouMsg = $("#subject").val();

if($subjectForThankYouMsg == "Home"){
    $(".lead_form_thankyou").text("Thank you for choosing our Car.");

}

else if($subjectForThankYouMsg == "Car"){
    $(".lead_form_thankyou").text("Thank you for choosing our Home.'+\n+' We will be in touch with you shortly.");

}
```

**My Issue**

Im finding it hard to mix jQuery and PHP and assign `$subjectForThankYouMsg` value to a session. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You can't use same string ("subject") multiple times as element ID in DOM.

Comment: Im not. These are 2 seperate forms on 2 seperate pages

Answer (score 0):

```
$subjectForThankYouMessage = <?php echo $_REQUEST['subject'] ?>;
```

you can change `$_REQUEST` (which is not recommended by PHP community, security issue) with either `$_POST` or `$_GET`, or even better `$_COOKIE` based on your form action, anyway